# wxHtmlListbox as a control in wxListbook

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to use wxListbook in my app, but I need multiline choices with different text format of each line.

Is it possible to use wxHtmlListbox as a control in wxListbook and how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want. You can certainly have the HtmlListbox as a child widget of each page in the Listbook widget. You just add it to each page element as necessary. Here's a fairly simple example:

```
import images
import wx

class MyHtmlListBox(wx.HtmlListBox):

    def OnGetItem(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return "This is item# <b>%d</b>" % n
        else:
            return "This is item# <b>%d</b> <br>Any <font color='RED'>HTML</font> is okay." % n

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        hlb = MyHtmlListBox(self, -1, size=(150, 250), style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        hlb.SetItemCount(50)
        hlb.SetSelection(0)



########################################################################
class ListbookDemo(wx.Listbook):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Listbook.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, 
                             style=wx.BK_DEFAULT)
        # make an image list using the LBXX images
        il = wx.ImageList(32, 32)
        for x in range(3):
            obj = getattr(images, 'LB%02d' % (x+1))
            bmp = obj.GetBitmap()
            il.Add(bmp)
        self.AssignImageList(il)

        pages = [(MyPanel(self), "Panel One"),
                 (MyPanel(self), "Panel Two"),
                 (MyPanel(self), "Panel Three")]
        imID = 0
        for page, label in pages:
            self.AddPage(page, label, imageId=imID)
            imID += 1

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.OnPageChanged)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING, self.OnPageChanging)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnPageChanged(self, event):
        old = event.GetOldSelection()
        new = event.GetSelection()
        sel = self.GetSelection()
        print 'OnPageChanged,  old:%d, new:%d, sel:%d\n' % (old, new, sel)
        event.Skip()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnPageChanging(self, event):
        old = event.GetOldSelection()
        new = event.GetSelection()
        sel = self.GetSelection()
        print 'OnPageChanging, old:%d, new:%d, sel:%d\n' % (old, new, sel)
        event.Skip()

########################################################################
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Listbook Tutorial",
                          size=(700,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = ListbookDemo(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The `images` module is from the wxPython demo. I also uploaded it to github: https://gist.github.com/driscollis/71312903470d9cf48f7c

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I want to change the standart ListBox control in ListBook, which switch the pages on HtmlListBox with multiline choices.

Comment: Then you will almost certainly need to create a custom widget to do that